# Is there a way to know when the Facebook Developers publish changes to the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, health-monitoring

An application I support was broken today by what I believe was an undocumented change to the API.

How do developers of sites that rely on Facebook monitor the API for changes?

I am aware of the Developer blog and I'm sure there are other "non automated" ways, but I'm specifically interested in any automated services available to health check the parts of the API that are critical to my app.

I'm also aware of the "platform status" page, http://developers.facebook.com/live_status but this is just a basic "is Facebook alive" check.

Any ideas or experience to share?

Should I set up a series of automated test cases with a tool like Watin or Selenium?
[Watin](http://watin.org/) or [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Or is there a specific Facebook tool / RSS feed available?

Also: does anyone know if the Facebook team publishes a public schedule or timetable of release notes when a build or API change set goes "live", that could be used to trigger an automated test? Anyone doing this successfully willing to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automated release notes or definite changelog, but there is an RSS feed showing the date of the most recent push to production: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/api_status.php

The `push` item contains the date and time that Facebook's code was last pushed